# How to animate a bone from it's current position - no matter which one - to a specific one?

Tags: animation

I want to make an animation where a bone rotates from any position to a specific position.

I've already made set of animations and each one starts form the idle position, 
but I want to make the current animation start from the end of previous one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a better control over the animation you should use a ***Dope Sheet Editor***.
In example below I rotate the *arm bone* and *hand bone*. The motion starts from 'idle' position and ends in 'bent' position. The yelow dots in *Dope Sheet Editor* window represent the keyframes. 
[image]

If you want for example to reverse this motion you go to the last keyframe, hover the cursor over the *Dope Sheet Editor* window, press <kbd>S</kbd> and input the value -1. Now the motion starts from 'bent' pose. 
[image]

The last thing you may do is to place the animation at the begining of the timeline. You can make it by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> button, while hovering the cursor over the *Dope Sheet Editor* window.
[image]

Comment: Hope I understood what you're asking for. Your question is not very clear :).

Comment: If the hand not in the idle position and i want to move it to bent the arm will back to idle position than to bent position what i want is to rotate the arm whatever the position is to bent position